# When are classes with prescribed reducts "pseudo"-elementary?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, set-theory, model-theory, factorization-theory

Let $\mathsf{Set}$ be the class of all sets and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a first-order language. Let $M \subseteq \mathsf{Set}$ be a set of $\mathcal{L}$-structures and let $$\mathfrak{Th}_{\in}(M) = \\ \{\sigma(\mathfrak A) \mid \sigma(\mathfrak A) \text{ is a } \in\text{-formula in one free variable } \mathfrak A \land \mathsf{ZFC} \models \forall \mathfrak A \in M \ \sigma(\mathfrak A)\}.$$
Let $$T(\mathfrak A) = \{\sigma(\mathfrak A) \in \mathfrak{Th}_{\in}(M) \mid \exists \varphi \ (\varphi \text{ is a sentence of } \mathcal{L} \land \mathsf{ZFC} \models \forall \mathfrak A \ (\mathfrak A \text{ is an } \mathcal L-\text{structure } \Rightarrow (\sigma(\mathfrak A) \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak A \models \varphi)))\}$$ be the set of all formulas in $\mathfrak{Th}_{\in}(M)$ that can be expressed in terms of $\mathcal{L}$ when assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or alternatively any other set theory). Moreover, let $\Sigma(\mathfrak A) \subseteq \mathfrak{Th}_{\in}(M)$.

**Question:** Is there a general method of proving or disproving that there exists an $\mathcal L$-structure $\mathfrak A$ such that $ \mathsf{ZFC} \models T(\mathfrak A) \cup \Sigma(\mathfrak A)$ that is not in $M$? If not, is there even work or literature going into this direction?

We are particularly interested in the case when $\Sigma$ consists of only one sentence that says: "The reducts of any two elements of $M$ to a fixed sublanguange $\mathcal L'$ of $\mathcal L$ are isomorphic."

---

The original motivation for this question is the following:

For this post, a monoid is a cancellative, commutative semigroup with identity element. To every element $a$ in a monoid $H$ we associate the set $\mathsf L(a)$ of all lengths of factorizations of $a$ as a product of irreducible elements of $H$. For convenience, if $a$ is invertible (resp. has no such factorization), we set $\mathsf L(a) = \{0\}$. We denote by $\mathfrak L(H) = \{\mathsf L(a) \mid a \in H\}$. In this way, we get a map $\mathfrak L: \mathsf{Mon} \to \mathsf{Set}$ (where $\mathsf{Mon}$ denotes the class of monoids) that sends a monoid $H$ to $\mathfrak L(H)$, and we denote by $M = \mathfrak L(\mathsf{Mon})$ its image.

A natural question to ask is whether we can characterize the set $M$ by sentences in a language fitting the problem, that is: "For which sets $\mathfrak L \subseteq \mathfrak P(\mathbb N)$ exists a monoid $H$ such that $\mathfrak L(H) = \mathfrak L$?"
For example, it is obvious for a monoid $H$ that for all $L_1,L_2 \in \mathfrak L(H)$ there exists $L \in \mathfrak L(H)$ such that $L_1+L_2 \subseteq L$ (where $+$ denotes elementwise addition of the sets). Another necessary condition is that $\{0\},\{1\} \in \mathfrak L(H) \subseteq \{\{0\},\{1\}\} \cup \mathfrak P(\mathbb N_{\geq 2})$ . We want to give a proposal for a suitable language in the following:

Let $\mathcal L = \{+, \subseteq, \mathfrak L, (c_k)_{k \in \mathbb N} \}$, where $+$ is a $2$-ary function symbol, $\subseteq$ is a $2$-ary relation symbol, $\mathfrak L$ is a unary relation symbol and $c_k$ is a constant symbol for each $k \in \mathbb N$. The intended interpretation of $\mathcal L$ on $\mathfrak L(H)$ for a monoid $H$ is the following: $+$ and $\subseteq$ should have their actual meanings as set addition and set theoretic inclusion on the set $\mathfrak P(\mathbb N)$, while for an element $L \in \mathfrak P(\mathbb N)$, we have $\mathfrak L(L)$ if and only if $L \in \mathfrak L(H)$. Lastly, $c_k$ should be interpreted as the singleton set $\{k\}$ for every $k \in \mathbb N$.

Now, to come to an end, we want to have $\Sigma(\mathfrak A)$ is the set only containing the following formula in the free variable $\mathfrak A$: "The reduct of $\mathfrak A$ to the language $\{+,\subseteq,(c_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}\}$ is $(\{\{0\},\{1\}\} \cup \mathfrak P(\mathbb N_{\geq 2}), +, \subseteq, (\{k\})_{k \in \mathbb N})$, where $+$ denotes actual set addition and $\subseteq$ is set theoretic inclusion."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure the definition of $\mathfrak{Th}_\in(M)$ makes sense. If $M$ is an arbitrary set of $L$-structures, how do you express $\forall \mathfrak{A}\in M\, \sigma(\mathfrak{A})$ as a sentence in the language of set theory? Of course, you can do this if the set $M$ is *definable* in the language of set theory, i.e. there is a formula $\varphi(x)$ such that a structure is in $M$ if and only if it satisfies $\varphi$. But then $\mathfrak{Th}_\in(M)$ is axiomatized by the single formula $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$. There's a similar issue when you write $ZFC \models T(A)\cup \Sigma(A)$.

Comment: I think the question would be much clearer if you rewrote it without mentioning the language of set theory. As far as I can tell, it seems like you're essentially asking the following question: "Let $M$ be a class of $L$-structures, all of which satisfy a property $P$. Among $L$-structures satisfying $P$, is $M$ is axiomatizable by a first-order $L$-theory? We are particularly interested in the case when $P$ says: the $L'$-reduct is  $N$ (for some fixed sublanguage $L'\subseteq L$ and some fixed $L'$-structure $N$.)" Is that right?

Comment: In the motivational case, the set $M$ is definable. Anyway, you are right. I will rewrite the question as soon as possible. Thanks for your comments!